# Progress dialog box of ArcGIS Python script tool stealing focus from TKinter GUI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool, tkinter

I created a script tool in the custom toolbox, it runs like this:

[image: The GUI of my python script tool]

But the default progress dialog keep stealing focus from the Tkinter GUI, that makes me so hard to move/resize the OpenFileDialog, expand the dropdown menu, double-click to choose item... ...

I have to right-click on the file to select it, paste the path into the inputbox to change the location.

Is there any way to avoid this or disable the default progress dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your Tkinter code into the tool validation part (Tool>Properties>Validation>Edit), around parameter initialization, you should be fine. However this is not an advised method due to architectural discordances. Still you can use Python add-ins as suggested in [Recommendations about graphic interface for ArcPy/Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133354/recomendations-about-graphic-interface-for-arcpy-python-script) and [Trying to use Tkinter to open dialog box in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144175/trying-to-use-tkinter-to-open-dialog-box-in-arcmap).